# Spring Web Flow - form:radiobutton

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

Can anybody help me understand what wrong here?

This is fragment from Spring web flow project. I create new object ***order*** and get a list of ***tables*** object from DB in  tag of view state.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow.xsd">

    <input name="order" required="true" />

    <view-state id="chooseTable" model="flowScope.order">
        <on-entry>
            <set name="flowScope.order" value="new pizza.Order()"></set>
            <evaluate expression="pizzaFlowActions.getFreeTables()"
                result="viewScope.tables" />
        </on-entry>
        <transition on="chosenCreateOrder" to="bookedToOrder">
        <evaluate expression="order.setTable(flowScope.order)" />
        </transition>
        <transition on="chosenNoOrder" to="booked">
        <evaluate expression="order.setTable(flowScope.order)" />
        </transition>
        <transition on="cancel" to="cancel" />
    </view-state>

    <end-state id="cancel" />

    <end-state id="bookedToOrder">
    </end-state>

    <end-state id="booked">
    </end-state>

    <global-transitions>
        <transition on="cancel" to="cancel" />
    </global-transitions>
</flow>
```

Jsp file with form with which object ***order*** is binded, and radiobuttons' values extracted from ***tables list***.

```
<html xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form">

<jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />

<head>
<title>Book a table</title>

</head>
<body background = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/plan.gif">
    <form:form commandName="order" class="box login">
    <input type="hidden" name="_flowExecutionKey" value="${flowExecutionKey}" />        
        <b>Choose table: </b>
        <c:forEach items="${tables}" var="place">   
           <form:radiobutton path="table" label="${place}" value="${place}"/>
        <br></br> 
        <br></br>   
        </c:forEach>
        <input type="submit" class="btnLogin" name="_eventId_chosenCreateOrder" value="Now choose Pizza" />
        <input type="submit" class="btnLogin" name="_eventId_chosenNoOrder" value="Just book a table" />
        <input type="submit" class="btnLogin" name="_eventId_cancel" value="Cancel" />
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Piece of Order class

```
public class Order implements Serializable {
private static final Logger LOGGER = getLogger(Order.class);
private int id;
private Customer customer;
private Set<Pizza> pizzas;
private Payment payment;
private Place table;
```

The problem here is that after choosing any variant any time the form just reloading and nothing happens more.

Will appreciate any help and hints.

Comment: I would suggest you send the id of the place you are trying to submit, then look it up and set it in your order. Or send the index of the place, so you can find it in your table list and set it in your order in you flow

Comment: Really, that's all I had to do.

Comment: so I am guessing it worked?

Comment: I had to use simple html radio element with id as table id